# How to convert timestamp with 6digit milliseconds using to_timestamp function in pyspark

Tags: string, pyspark, timestamp

I have a timestamp column in my dataframe with timestamps in a format like: 2022-07-28T10:38:50.926866Z that are currently strings.

I want to convert this column into actual timestamps and I've searched around but every time I try to_timestamp with this type of data I get nulls.

Things I've tried:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2022-07-28T10:38:50.926866Z",)],['date_str'])

df.withColumn("ts1", F.to_timestamp(col('date_str'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'")).show(truncate=False)
```

This always gets me null but when I run something similar on an example with just 3 ms digits, it seems to work:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2022-07-28T10:38:50.926Z",)],['date_str'])

df.withColumn("ts1", F.to_timestamp(col('date_str'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")).show(truncate=False)
```

I'm completely lost on how to handle this string conversion.

Comment: Which spark are you using? Both examples seem to work just fine on pyspark 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving this by removing the last 4 characters of each timestamp string first and then running the to_timestamp. I don't mind losing the ms so this worked for me.

```
df = df.withColumn("date_str", F.substring("date_str", 1, 23))
df.withColumn("date_str", F.to_timestamp(df_final.date_str, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show()
```