# To_Timestamp in Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, datetime, pyspark, timestamp, datetime-format

I would like to convert a spark df column, which has this structure: **Thu, 24 Mar 2016 14:29:20 237111 +0900**

As there is a day of week, I set the spark config to LEGACY (`spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")`)

When I query the result, it is giving NULL. I also found out this datetime format via [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Here is my code:

```
data.withColumn("timestamp_res", to_timestamp(col("timestamp_str"), 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss SSSSSS Z'))
```

Comment: this looks similar to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73168037

Comment: Yes, but the user loses some ms, I dont want to.

Comment: can you try removing the LEGACY config and try `df.select(to_timestamp(substring('date', 6, 100), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss SSSSSS Z'))`?